# BigQuery Syntax Error : SELECT list expression references column UnitPrice which is neither grouped nor aggregated at [5:1]

Tags: group-by, google-bigquery

```sql
SELECT
  EXTRACT(YEAR FROM Date) as Year,
  EXTRACT(MONTH FROM Date) as Month,
  ProductId,
  UnitPrice,
  Quantity,
  (UnitPrice * Quantity) AS Total_price,
FROM sales.sales_info
GROUP BY
  Year,
  Month,
  ProductId
ORDER BY
  Year,
  Month,
  ProductId;
```

Answer (score 0):

Which aggregated function are you using? Do not see any aggregated function in select.
Also in group by UnitPrice and Quantity column are missing.